# Correct way to customize bootstrap theme (Using SCSS source files)

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-4

Right now I have all the unmodified bootstrap files  a copy of those files for customization.

These folders:

--> Bootstrap
--> Custom (copy of the above)

I first include boostrap files and then the custom files, which right now are an exact copy.

Let's say I start changing values in "Custom" in order to get the desired looks. Then I update boostrap to a new version, by updating the bootstrap folder. A lot of changes might not come through since the previous version is basically copied to "Custom" even if the css rules haven't been changed at all.

Is this the correct way to do it, or should I try a different approach?

Comment: There is no need to have an exact copy of the BS CSS file. the "custom" CSS file should only involve the **changes** you want to make. Because it overrides the BS file because it's loaded after.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do this

First i need to understand you project folder struture i would reccomend this

```
dist
 -/css
   -/styles.css
src
 -/scss
   -styles.scss
   -/bootstrap
      -bootstrap.scss (taken from the scss folder)
      -_variables.scss (taken from the scss folder)
```

Using this stucture your project only needs the styles.scss which will import the bootstrap folder below it and then compile into your dist folder to ouput your CSS (i would reccommend webpack or gulp for this if you know how to do thiat)

The main this in that the bootstrap.scss file is set-up like this below (in this example i am using node_modules as i have imported bootstrap using npm into my project. But this is a relative path for where the files live, so make your path to the same files is correct to how you have strutured your project)

**Bootstrap.scss**

Just notice that the variables file is pointing to the local one, not the one that sits in the main repo folder.

```
/*!
 * Bootstrap v4.2.1 (https://getbootstrap.com/)
 * Copyright 2011-2018 The Bootstrap Authors
 * Copyright 2011-2018 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 */

@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "../bootstrap/_variables.scss";
/*@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables.scss";*/
@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/root";
@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/reboot";
@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/type";
@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/images";
@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/code";
@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/grid";
@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/tables";
@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/forms";
@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/buttons";
@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/transitions";
@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/dropdown";
@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/button-group";
@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/input-group";
@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/custom-forms";
@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/nav";
@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/navbar";
@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/card";
@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/breadcrumb";
@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/pagination";
@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/badge";
@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/jumbotron";
@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/alert";
@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/progress";
@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/list-group";
@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/close";
@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/toasts";
@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/modal";
@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/tooltip";
@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/popover";
@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/carousel";
@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/spinners";
@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/utilities";
```

**Styles.scss**

This is the file that you will need to complie and then that will output your custom CSS

```
@import 'bootstrap/bootstrap.scss';
```

the [variables](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/scss/_variables.scss) file so long as you copied this from the repo version you are using (important as with the various version, if you use the incorrect version then you will get complie errors for variables not being present) You should be able to customise bootstrap colours, breakpoints, cols, rows and much more to get bootstrap the way you want it.